# ObjectListItem "press" event is not fired

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, sapui5

Whether this

```
<List id="list" items="{/Report}">
      <items> 
          <ObjectListItem   press="onSelect"  title="{TYPE}"> </ObjectListItem>
      </items>
</List>
```

nor this

```
<List id="list" items="{/Report}" itemPress="onSelect">
       <items> 
           <ObjectListItem   title="{TYPE}"> </ObjectListItem>
       </items>
</List>
```

fires

```
onSelect : function (oEvent) {
    'use strict';
    console.log("onSelect");
}
```

in the Controller.

What may cause this? There is no related error message in the console.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default ObjectListItem type is set to InActive. If its set to any other type, say 'Active' the press event will be triggered.

```
<ObjectListItem
        press="onSelect"
        title="{TYPE}"
        type = "Active">
</ObjectListItem>
```

https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/docs/api/symbols/sap.m.ListType.html

https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.m.ListBase.html#event:itemPress